# jQuery replace table rows with new data

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I'm trying to replace a table with new data I get via ajax. The first time works just fine, but then the rows get added instead of replaced, so I end up with duplicate rows.

Here's some of my code:

```
            success: function(data){            
            $("#featured_listing_tbody").children( 'tr:not(:first)' ).remove();
            counter= 1;
            $.each(data, function(i, val){  
                        newPropertyRows += '<tr>';
                                $.each(val, function(key, info){
                                    var skip = false;
                                        if(key == "Id") {                                           
                                                Id =  info;
                                                newPropertyRows += '';
                                                skip = true;
                                        }
                                        if(key == "thumbs"){
                                                info = '<img width="100px" src=uploads/properties/'+Id+'/thumbs/'+info+' />';
                                                newPropertyRows += '<td class="col'+counter+'"><a href="/featured.php?prop='+Id+'">'+info+'</a></td>';  
                                                skip = true;
                                                counter++;      
                                        }
                                        if(skip == false){
                                                newPropertyRows += '<td class="col'+counter+'"><a href="/featured.php?prop='+Id+'">'+info+'</a></td>';                      
                                                counter++;      
                                        }

                                        info = '';
                                });                     
                        newPropertyRows += '</tr>';                         
            });                     
                $("#featured_listing_tbody").html(newPropertyRows);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem is not in the part of code which you posted. For example in the current code you use always `+=` operation with the `newPropertyRows` variable. **Are you reset it to empty string** before every ajax call?

By the way it seems to me that you don't call `$("#featured_listing_tbody").children( 'tr:not(:first)' ).remove()` at the beginning of `success` handler because you use `$("#featured_listing_tbody").html(newPropertyRows);` later which will overwrite the whole body of the table.

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion, instead of returning a data object and converting it to HTML in javascript, just return the data as the required table rows. As you're already generating them for the page you should have the logic/template to do it again easily.

To replace the data I would just include a `<tbody>` tag around your data rows, and in your ajax success function just replace its contents - instead of doing the complicated selector to omit the first table row which I assume are you column headers.

```
$("#featured_listing tbody").html(data); //Replace contents of <tbody> tag
```

And the table:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>....row headers...</tr></thead>
    <tbody>...data rows...</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ok i understand an like the idea. but as the results grow over time i'm afraid the extra data will slow down the process. am i crazy(don't awnser that lol)

Comment: Downloading a few table rows and spitting them out will be quicker than looping through a data and creating them on the fly, especially with those counters and stuff. That way the load is on your server and not on the users (potentially stone age) browser.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if you store the record for the table or it's real-time and not stored anywhere.

But if it's stored, you could try generating the html for the entire table or just the rows at the server side and then simply replace the container / table content with the data received from the server.